# Single word for "worth to consider"

Tags: word-request

First I thought its `considerable`, but seems there's no such meaning after I consulted the dict.

Is there a single word for "worth to consider"?

Context:

`This tool looks promising, its considerable? to introduce into our current tech stack`

Comment: The adjective "worthy" itself, in the right context, means exactly that: _"a worthy argument"_, e.g. Consider (!) also _meritorious_ in a similar context.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/considerable (it says *worth consideration*)

Answer (score 1):

> [**"Worthwhile"**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/worthwhile) (adj) : useful, important, or helpful enough to be a suitable reward for the money or time spent or the effort made: *She considers teaching a worthwhile career.*

Short for the idiomatic expression: "(to be) worth your while".

> My brother said it would be *worthwhile* for me to meditate every morning.